# Email from spreadsheet Javascript: How to make message equal more than one column?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

A colleague and I are using Google Forms to collect short essays from students. The Data is written to a spreadsheet. We want to type the feedback into the spreadsheet and have a script email each student a copy of their essay and the feedback.

Google provides the following code (source: [Email Code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails)):

We have figured out how to increase the number of rows the script reads from the spreadsheet to account for our class sizes.

What we can't figure out is how to make the message equal both the essay (in one column) and the feedback (in another column). What do we need to change in the code to make this happen?

Comment: have you tried to add those two columns? Something like `var message = row[1] + row[2];`

Comment: probably more readable to send a html email documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object))

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to a [demo spreadsheet and script](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ce2JIZq2G2Kr-wUz9Qd0uZSkG1rZrWs2Iq9p-4k_d2A/edit?usp=sharing). Just make a copy of the spreadsheet and test out the code.

Test the script by highlighting 1 or more rows of data in the spreadsheet and running `emailFeedback` function from the Script Editor. Or, you with 1 or more rows selected you can execute the script from the "Custom Tools" menu in the spreadsheet.

I split this up into two functions. The first function `emailFeedback` gets the rows you selected in the spreadsheet and loops through each row of data and calls the second function `sendEmail` for each row, provided there is feedback and text (more validation and error handling could be added).

```
function emailFeedback() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = ss.getActiveRange(); 

  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var values = range.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    var to = row[1];
    var story = row[2];
    var feedback = row[3]; 

    if (feedback.length > 0 && story.length > 0) {
      // make sure valid story and feedback before sending
      sendEmail(to, story, feedback);
    }
  }
};
```

`GmailApp` is used to send the email with html formatting as suggested by **igor** in the comments above. The `plainTxtBody` can likely be omitted, but perhaps useful if the recipient can't parse the html formatted email. `storyHTML` and `feedbackHTML` replace newline characters from user form submissions with `<p>` tags so you get proper spacing in the email.

```
function sendEmail(to, story, feedback) {
  var sendToName = to.split('@')[0];

  // email content
  var emailSubject = "Feedback on your story submission";

  // plain text body - just in case receiver can't parse html formatted email
  var plainTxtBody = "Hi " + sendToName + ",\n" +
                     "You wrote:\n" + story + "\n" +
                     "Our feedback:\n" + feedback;

  // html formatting isn't necessary, but nice for reading :)
  var htmlBody = '<html><body>';
  var htmlFooter = '</body></html>';

  // replacing newline characters with paragraph breaks to make it more readable
  var storyHTML = story.replace(/\n/g, "</p><p>");
  var feedbackHTML = feedback.replace(/\n/g, "</p><p>");

  var emailMessage = "<p>Hi " + sendToName + ",</p>" +
                     "<p><strong>You wrote:</strong><p>" +
                     "<p>" + storyHTML + "</p>" +
                     "<hr>" + 
                     "<p><strong>Here is our feedback:</strong></p>" + 
                     "<p>" + feedbackHTML + "</p>";


  htmlBody += emailMessage + htmlFooter;

  // GmailApp must have default recipient, subject, body attributes followed by jsobject options {}
  // Differs from MailApp syntax but has more options -- see documentation on GmailApp
  GmailApp.sendEmail(to, emailSubject, plainTxtBody, { 
                     htmlBody: htmlBody,
                    });
};
```

Hope this is helpful :)